# xml mapping using Class in Python without error

Tags: python, xml, class

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from pprint import pprint

class xml_mapping:
    def read_field(xml_node, name):
        return [child.get(name) for child in xml_node.iter('field')]

    def read_map(xml_node):
        f = root.attrib
        dict1 = {f['name']:['input_layer','output_layer','fields']}
        dict1[f['name']][0] = {
            'input_layer': root.find('input_layer').get('name'),
        }
        dict1[f['name']][1] = {
            'output_layer': root.find('output_layer').get('name'),
        }

        for child in xml_node:
            if child.tag == 'field_mapping':
                fields = {}
                for field_name in ['input_name','output_name']:
                    fields[field_name] = read_field(child, field_name)
                dict1[f['name']][2] = {
                    'fields': dict(zip(fields['output_name'],fields['input_name'])),
                }

        return dict1

c = xml_mapping
tree = ET.parse('substation.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
pprint (c.read_map(root))
```

When I tried this I am getting an error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Python27\final_xml_mapping_f.py", line 25, in <module>
    pprint (c.read_map(root))
TypeError: read_map() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Somebody Pls help me to clear this.

Comment: I tried it without using class and I got the output I wanted. So pls help me to do this in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

- Your method declaration is missing the `self` parameter.
- You are not instantiating your class

For example:

```
class xml_mapping(object):
    def read_fields(self, xml_node, name):
        # ...

    def read_map(self, xml_node):  # needs implicit self parameter
        self.read_fields(x, y)  # call another method

instance = xml_mapping()  # instantiate class
instance.read_map(argument)  # call method
```

The implicit `self` argument refers to the instance.

### Alternatives

If you don't want to instantiate the class you can declare a `classmethod` or a `staticmethod`. These can both be called on the class itself, without an instance:

```
class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def bar(cls, arg):
        print arg

    @staticmethod
    def baz(arg):
        print arg

Foo.bar(1)
Foo.baz(2)
```

In the `classmethod` version, the function gets an implicit `cls` argument, which is the class itself. The `staticmethod` version gets no implicit arguments.

You probably don't want to do that unless you have a good reason to do so.